# Selenium not getting HTML of PDF links

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download the PDF slides off this [website](https://mila.umontreal.ca/en/cours/deep-learning-summer-school-2017/slides/) using Python and selenium but I think the the links to the slides only appear after loading a script. I tried waiting for the javascript to load but it's still not finding anything. Any ideas?

```
import os, sys, time, random
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://mila.umontreal.ca/en/cours/deep-learning-summer-school-2017/slides'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(3)
html = browser.page_source
links = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('flip-entry')
print(links)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: At first glance: Why are you setting `html = browser.page_source` and not using `html` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that there are no links on the main page. You are getting links inside an IFrame. This IFrame points to https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?hl=fr&id=0ByUKRdiCDK7-c0k1TWlLM1U1RXc#list

[image: IFrame]

You can either directly browse that URL in your code instead of main page. Or you can switch to the frame

```
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_class_name("iframe-class"))
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.flip-entry a')

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://mila.umontreal.ca/en/cours/deep-learning-summer-school-2017/slides'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_class_name('iframe-class'))
links = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('.flip-entry a')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
browser.quit()
```